# jQuery returns undefined unexpectedly

Tags: jquery

The jsfiddle link is http://jsfiddle.net/PrfZy/1/

The code is:

```
$button = $('<button />', { text: "Some text.", name: "myButton"});
alert($button.attr("name"));
alert($button.attr("text"));
```

Why is the second alert "undefined"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valid attributes for a `<button>` are `name`,`type`,`value` and `disabled` (which is actually considered a property and should be set and accessed via `prop()`).

You can create a custom attribute (which won't validate) using the attribute setters:

```
$button = $('<button />').attr('text','Some text.').attr('name','myButton');
alert($button.attr('name'));
alert($button.attr("text"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/PrfZy/2/

The valid syntax is as follows:

```
$button = $('<button />').text('Some text.').attr('name','myButton');
alert($button.attr('name'));
alert($button.text());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/PrfZy/3/

Of course, the compromise of the two would be to set a valid HTML5 custom data attribute and access it via `data()`

```
$button = $('<button />').attr('data-text','Some text.').attr('name','myButton');
alert($button.attr('name'));
alert($button.data('text'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/PrfZy/4/

Comment: That doesn't work on this page. Try this in the console `$('a').slice(0,1).attr('text', 'Foo').attr('text');`; **SO** uses jQuery 1.52.

Comment: Ah, I guess it does with `button`

Comment: @Josh: What is **SO**? And why did you try to use `.slice()`?

Comment: @Randomblue SO is short for **Stack Overflow**. `slice` is the proper way to get a truncated jQuery object http://api.jquery.com/slice/ (no need to operate on every anchor contained in this page).

Comment: Resig, the original creator of jQuery also mentions `slice` as the right way in this video http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=-474821803269194441

Answer (score 2):

`text` isn't an `attr`, so if you change that line to this `alert($button.text());` you will get your expect result.